# difference between put your hand up and raise your hand?

Tags: difference

If I asked my teacher a question in a classroom, then which one of the following sentence would be correct ?

1. I put my hand up to ask the teacher a question.
2. I raised my hand up to ask the teacher a question.

Is there any difference ? - If any, how to differentiate its usage ?

Comment: there both technically the same, but raising your hand is much more common, specifically when dealing with raising your hand in order to be called on.

Comment: *It's* in your last question should be *its*. You need the possessive, not the contraction of *it is*.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if it's a British/American thing, but in my corner of Britain (Swansea), we tend to use "put your hand up" when you have a question for a teacher. I can't really comment on the usage across the rest of Britain, but "raise your hand" is something that I've only really come across in American sitcoms and films.

Comment: Welcome to ELL! I think it would be better if you did an expansion to your answer. Right now it gives me the feeling that it's a comment.

Comment: @MARamezani Actually, it seems to me to be a perfectly good answer. It offers an explanation for what the difference might be: AmE vs. BrE.

Comment: they just have to always pick holes

Answer (score 4):

There is a strong "British-American difference".

The [Corpus of Contemporary American English](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/) contains 196 citations of *raise your hand,* but only 7 of *put up your hand.*

If you want to follow "US" style, it would be *I raised my hand,* not *raised my hand up*. If you want to follow "UK/British" style, it would be *I put my hand up.*

Answer (score 3):

Another difference: If a policeman was arresting a bad guy, he'd be more likely to say, "Put your hands up" than "Raise your hands".

Answer (score -1):

Raise is same as up and so "raise up your hand" in grammar is malapropism . it is therefore appropriate to say put up your hand or raise your hand.

Answer (score -2):

If you " put up " your hand you can " put down"  your hand easily.. If you " raise your hand " still you have to " put down " your hand .

Put up your hand × put down your hand

Raise your hand × ? ( Put down your hand )(◔‿◔)